# parseJSON discards variables starting with underscore

Tags: jquery, json

I am using cherrypy and mongo for a small web application. At some point I want to have a method that returns the object id to a template, '_id' if you may, but parseJSON dismisses it completely. I could rewrite my documents and methods but I was wondering if there is another way around this. In python, I return a dictionary like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.auth(level='mortal')
def add(self, **params):
    if cherrypy.request.method == 'POST':
        # do stuff
        return json.dumps(article)
```

and in jquery I try to parse it (including the _id variable):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/org/add',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data._id);
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

all other variables are returned except _id :( can you help me out on this one?

I'm using python 2.7.5 and jquery 1.8 btw.

Comment: Please post your JSON string received.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I just found the issue (in my mongo class of course). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arhea/GME9S/ and it does not remove underscore properties. It must be your backend code not sending it through. But it should not be the javascript.